# Pig Latin keeping special characters python

Tags: python, function

I am new to programming and I have a simple pig latin code. Just wanted some advice on how the code can ignore special characters, meaning they are returned to the same place.
For instance, in pig latin if a word begins with a vowel you add 'hay' to the end:
   `if word[0] in VOWELS: 
        print (word + "hay",end=' ')`
so egg would become egghay
however if the input was !.egg how can I ignore the !. so it becomes !.egghay

Is there a way to write code in which each character is looked at and if it is not in string.ascii_letter it is temporarily ignored.

`
Thanks

Comment: Pig latin has absolutely nothing to do with apache-pig, a graph computational language for running map-reduce tasks on hadoop clusters.

Answer (score 0):

`if not word[0].isalpha():
    word = word[1:]`

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

This obviously also fails with multiple initial special characters, but `isalpha` might be helpful.